Mistake in a proof of the Hockey Stick identity
I'm trying to compute the following sum
$$\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{i+m}{m}$$
By a change of index, this is equal to the Hockey stick identity (wikipedia):
$$\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{i+m}{m} = \sum_{i=m}^{n+m} \binom{i}{m} =  \binom{n+m+1}{m+1}$$
I defined my sum as $S(n,m)$. Note that $S(0,0)=1, S(n, 0)=n+1, S(0, m)=1$ and $S(n, m)$ is zero for negative values of $n, m$. Now, using the recurrence relation of binomial coefficient we get
$$S(n, m) = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{i+m}{m} = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{i+m-1}{m-1}+\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{i+m-1}{m}$$
Note that the first term is $S(n, m-1)$ and the second term is
$$\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{i+m-1}{m}=\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{i+m-1}{m} =\sum_{z=0}^{n-1} \binom{z+m}{m}=S(n-1, m)$$
where the first equality is because for $i=0$ the sum term is $0$, and the second equality is obtaining by changing the index $i-1=z$. So we have
$$S(n, m)=S(n-1, m)+S(n, m-1)$$
We prove by induction that
$$S(n, m) = \sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{k}{i} S(n-i, m-k+i)$$
Case $k=1$ is the above identity. To prove $k\rightarrow k+1$ use the above
$$S(n, m) = \sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{k}{i} S(n-i, m-k+i) = $$
$$\sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{k}{i} [S(n-i-1, m-k+i)+S(n-i, m-k+i-1)]$$
and the proof continues in a similar way to the proof of the binomial theorem.
Now let $k=n+m$:
$$S(n, m) = \sum_{i=0}^{n+m} \binom{n+m}{i} S(n-i, i-n)$$
For both $n-i$ and $i-n$ to be $\ge0$ we must have $i=n$, and all the other terms are $0$, so
$$S(n, m)= \binom{n+m}{n}=\binom{n+m}{m}$$
But this conclusion is wrong and in fact the right hand side is equal to $S(n, m-1)$. But i can't find a mistake in my proof. Where am I going wrong? I know there's many easier proofs but I want to see where I'm making the mistake here.

Apparently that identity of $S(n,m)$ and/or induction step may not work when the argument of $S$ is negative. For example, $S(n,0) = n+1$, while $S(n-1,0)+S(n,-1) = n+0$.

As pointed out by @peterwhy, for $m=0$, we get
$$S(n,0) = n + 1$$
And yet $$S(n,0) = S(n-1,0) + S(n-1) = n + 0 = n$$
One way to fix this would be to define $S(n,-1) = 1$.
And now if we continue with your proof, when we  consider:
$$S(n, m) = \sum_{i=0}^{n+m} \binom{n+m}{i} S(n-i, i-n)$$
We now have two non-zero terms at $n = i$ and $ n = i + 1$.
And so $$S(n, m) = \binom{n + m}{n}S(0,0) + \binom{n+m}{n-1}S(1,-1)$$
$$S(n,m) = \binom{n + m}{n} + \binom{n+m}{n-1} = \binom{n+m+1}{n} = \binom{n+m+1}{m + 1}$$
See here for proof of the final line.

The way I went about debugging your proof was just like how I would debug some code. I plugged in a value of $n$ and $m$ and went through line-by-line waiting for an equality to break.
